# Oracle Database Integration with Team Foundation Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, team-foundation-server

So my company is using TFS and SQL to Manage their Database (MS SQL Server). It integrates with the nightly build servers to do builds and produce scripts to build the entire Database. Also the Compare Schema tool that visual studio offers is really handy.

We want to do the same with Oracle, Preferably with TFS if that's even possible. It can be done without, but is this a possibility?

Also are there any tools to assist in automatically creating the Database in a Nightly Build?

What about Managing Upgrades?

Our Big worry is moving triggers and the MS SQL Service Broker to Oracle... this we might have to do manually though.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Well We've looked at Toad Extensions for Visual Studio, im more doing research for an "Idea meeting" basically. So nothing has been "tried" of yet. and I literally know zero about what's out there regarding this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with TFS - all TFS does is call MSBuild that (basically) runs visual studio in batch mode, so if you can get your DB project deploying to Oracle then TFS will be happy. (though you'll be much better off using Jenkins as it kicks TFS's bottom).

So, you have to get the VS project to deploy your DB project to an Oracle DB, now this should be possible - as you just have to specify a different connection string in the DB project settings (or the .dbdeployment file). Chances are you'll end up with SQLServer-specific sql generated and deployed, or VS will refuse to use anything other than a SQLClient connection.

So, go direct and get the [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) which will give you the same DB projects, and its own schema compare tool.